# Open new record in access

Tags: vba, record

I am looking for a way to have a form open on a new record after clicking a button.  All I seem to be able to do is have it open on (new), but the record is not actually created until text starts being typed.  I would like it to open actually ON a new record, with a new ID (primary key).  I need this ID for some other functionality that happens prior to the user entering new data into the form.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would insert a record into the given table using either SQL or DAO or ADO and then open a form to edit the given record.

An example for inserting a row using SQL:

```
Dim query As String
Dim newRow As Integer
query = "INSERT INTO Table (fieldname) VALUES (null);"
newRow = CurrentDb.Execute(query)
```

However, your approach has a weakness: if a user abandons the editing of a record, you are stuck with an empty record. I would rather re-assess the approach and would run any code that uses the id of the new record after I'm sure that the user wants to create the new record.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in!  My issue is that the end user would like to be able to copy part of an old record into a new record to avoid retyping.  They search via a subform and query and hit a button and some of the fields copy into the new record, and if they make a mistake run the search and copy a different record.  The only way I was able to get that to work was via an update query.  I have to have a new record already open to do this.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In this case I would use an unbound form to display the copied data. This way you can avoid creating a record unnecessarily. If the users decide to abandon the the new entry, there is no empty record created. If the users decide to save the record, then you can use SQL or ADO or DAO to save the form's data in the table.